# How to check for libhoudini availability?

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, arm

I'd like to use only the ARM version of a native library for my app. Supposedly, most current x86 devices ship a [compatibility mode, libhoudini](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/11/21/libhoudini-what-it-means-for-developers.html). However there is no guarantee that this compatibility mode is available. Is there any way to check for libhoudini availability on a device in Java code?

Comment: Have you checked if [`SUPPORTED_ABIS`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS) contains `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a`?

Comment: Haven't seen this, thanks. However, the constant was introduced in API level 21. My minSdkVersion is 16.

Comment: Just checked on an Asus x86 device: SUPPPORTED_ABIS = x86, armeabi-v7a, armeabi / CPU_ABI = x86 / CPU_ABI2 = armeabi-v7a - CPU_ABI and CPU_ABI being available prior to api level 21. The question is whether all libhoudini equipped devices will declare "armeabi-v7a" in these constants?

Comment: I wouldn't know about _all_, but here are a few devices from various manufacturers that do (check the build.prop tab): http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=8e55-9fd3-0033-c5870033c587 http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=847e-ed9c-ffff-ffff88d58b3c http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=1d91-d71e-781f-701c28f6335a http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=971d-77ea-fcc0-2b0c0033c587

Comment: A couple of things to consider: 1) The number of x86 devices without ARM compatibility is probably tiny; it's in Intel's best interest to make sure it's working on all "Intel Inside" devices. 2) If your loadlibrary call fails, then you know that your native code is not going to run.

Comment: Maybe shouldn't care about Android on x86 - see http://www.pcworld.com/article/3092192/android/intel-scales-back-android-development.html and http://www.pcworld.com/article/3063508/components/intel-is-on-the-verge-of-exiting-the-smartphone-and-tablet-markets-after-cutting-atom-chips.html

Comment: The article says that Intel/Google will focus on Chromebooks (which will run Android apps). So, maybe, you should care.